# Remove Rows Where the Person Has Not Changed Locations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to go through my dataframe two lines at a time, checking if a column value is the same in both rows and removing such rows. My dataframe tracks the locations of different people during different encounters.

I have a dataframe, called `transfers`, in which each row consists of an ID number for a person, an encounter number, and a location. The `transfers` dataframe was created by running a duplicated on my original dataframe to find rows with the same person ID, grouping them together.

For example, we would want to get rid of the rows with `ID = 2` in the dataframe below because the location was `"D"` in both encounters, so this person has not moved.

However, we would want to keep the rows with `ID = 3` because that person moved from `"A"` to `"F"`.

Another issue arises because some people have more than two rows, for example where `ID = 1`. For this person, we would want to keep their rows because they have moved from `"A"` -> `"B"` and then from `"B"` -> `"C"`. However, if you only compare the encounters 12 and 13, it does not look like this person has changed locations.

Example dataframe `df`:

```
ID  Encounter  Location
1      11         A
1      12         B
1      13         B
1      14         C
2      21         D
2      22         D
3      31         A
3      32         F
```

Expected output:

```
ID  Encounter  Location
1      11         A
1      12         B
1      13         B
1      14         C
3      31         A
3      32         F
```

I have tried a nested `for` loops using `.iterrows()`, but I found that this did not work as it was terribly slow and did not properly handle cases where the person had more than two encounters. I have also tried applying a function to my dataframe, but the runtime was nearly the same as crude looping.

EDIT: I should have explicitly stated this, I am trying to keep the data of any person who has moved locations even if they end up back where they started.

Comment: What if a person moves back to the starting location on the last move? Keep or drop?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this. I want to keep data for anyone who has moved locations, even if they end up back where they started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df                                                                                                                            
   ID  Encounter Location
0   1         11        A
1   1         12        B
2   1         13        B
3   1         14        C
4   2         21        D
5   2         22        D
6   3         31        A
7   3         32        F
```

you can filter your dataframe via

```
>>> places = df.groupby('ID')['Location'].transform('nunique')                                                                 
>>> df[places > 1]                                                                                                             
   ID  Encounter Location
0   1         11        A
1   1         12        B
2   1         13        B
3   1         14        C
6   3         31        A
7   3         32        F
```

The idea is to count the number of unique places per group (ID) and then drop the rows where a person has only been to one place.

---

Comparison versus the `filter` solution:

```
# setup
>>> df = pd.concat([df.assign(ID=df['ID'] + i) for i in range(1000)], ignore_index=True)                                          
>>> df                                                                                                                            
        ID  Encounter Location
0        1         11        A
1        1         12        B
2        1         13        B
3        1         14        C
4        2         21        D
...    ...        ...      ...
7995  1000         14        C
7996  1001         21        D
7997  1001         22        D
7998  1002         31        A
7999  1002         32        F

[8000 rows x 3 columns]
# timings @ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
>>> %timeit df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['Location'].nunique() > 1)                                                        
356 ms ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit df[df.groupby('ID')['Location'].transform('nunique') > 1]                                                             
5.56 ms ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. 
I realize this was kind of a simple question, but I am new to Pandas so I am still learning the most Cythonic way of doing things. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: @cecilj no problem. `pandas` is a huge library. You pick up tricks over time by reading questions and answers here.

Comment: Filter works well here, df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['Location'].nunique() > 1)

Comment: @Vaishali that's much slower if the number of groups is high. See edit.

Comment: Oh, that's slow. Thanks for the reply :)